# set NA to zero in a nested tibble

Tags: r, nested, dplyr, tidyr

I would like to set all `NA` of a nested tibble to `0`:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(x = c(1, 2, NA), y = c("a", NA, "b"), z = list(1:5, rep(NA,10), 10:20))
```

`replace_na` works well for a part of the tibble:

```
df %>% replace_na(list(x = 0, y = "0", z="doesnotwork")) -> df1
```

`df1$x` gives me:

```
[1] 1 2 0
```

however, in `df1$z` `NA` remains:

```
[[1]]  [1] 1 2 3 4 5
[[2]]  [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
[[3]]  [1] 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`df$z` is a list-column, so you need to use a `purrr` function to apply `replace_na` to each element of the list. Here we can just use `map` to apply `replace_na` to each vector in `df$z`, replacing all `NA` with `0`. Your syntax as above would replace missing list *elements* (marked by `NULL`) with `"doesnotwork"`, not missing values *inside* the list elements.

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(x = c(1, 2, NA), y = c("a", NA, "b"), z = list(1:5, rep(NA,10), 10:20))

df1 <- df %>%
  replace_na(list(x = 0, y = "0")) %>%
  mutate(z = map(z, replace_na, 0))
df1$z
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 1 2 3 4 5
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>  [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
#> 
#> [[3]]
#>  [1] 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

Created on 2018-05-08 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 3):

This could be also done with `rapply` (recursive apply) from `base R`

```
df[] <- rapply(df, function(x) replace(x, is.na(x),  0), how = 'list')
str(df)
#Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':  3 obs. of  3 #variables:
# $ x: num  1 2 0
# $ y: chr  "a" "0" "b"
# $ z:List of 3
#  ..$ : num  1 2 3 4 5
#  ..$ : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
#  ..$ : num  10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 ...
```

Comment: Nice solution! Just one question, why the brackets here `df[]`? Thanks

Comment: @lcgodoy  because `rapply` returns a `list` and the `[]` ensures that we have the structure of the 'df' instead of a `list`